# Use SSBO as VBO input for the next draw call

Tags: opengl, synchronization, shader, vbo

I write some vertex data inside a shader to SSBO. Then I want to use the data written to the SSBO as VBOs. These will be used for the next draw call. How can this be done?

Here is, how I do it now, but it still segfaults:

```
int new_vertex_count = …;
int new_index_count = …;
int* new_indices = …;

GLuint ssbo[3];
glGenBuffers(3, ssbo);


glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, new_vertex_count * 3 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo[1]);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo[2]);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, new_vertex_count * 2 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, ssbo[2]);

glBindVertexArray(vao); //bind the original VAO
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 16);
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD); //disable displaying
glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, index_count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); //don't draw, just 
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT); //sync writing
glFinish();
glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD); //reanable displaying for next draw call
glBindVertexArray(0); //unbind original VAO in order to use new VBOs


glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ssbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_count * sizeof(uint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ssbo[1]); //bind SSBO as VBO, is this even possible?
//or should I use new VBOs and copy? How would I copy then?
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ssbo[2]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, new_index_count, new_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); //here the real drawing
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as an "SSBO" or a "VBO". There are only buffer objects. Storage blocks and vertex arrays are uses for buffer objects, but a particular buffer is not inherently linked to a particular use. There's nothing stopping you from writing to a buffer through a storage block, then reading from it in a rendering operation.

So long as you follow the rules of [incoherent memory access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) for those writes, of course. Writes through a storage block are not available for reading operations unless you explicitly make them available. You would use `glMemoryBarrier` for this. And the way a [memory barrier works](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#External_visibility) is that the enumerator specifies the operations you want to be able to see the results of *whatever* was written.

You want the written data to be read as vertex attribute arrays. So you use:

```
glMemoryBarrier(GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT​);
```